# Jquery pause on hover for marquee

Tags: jquery

I found a jquery marquee, which i have implemented on my website. I am wondering what the best way would be to add a pause on hover function. As the marquee contains links, i'd like it to pause when a user hovers over to click the link.

Any help or feedback would be appreciated.

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>

 <script>  $(document).ready(function() {
$("#marq").fadeIn();
$('.marquee').marquee({

//speed in milliseconds of the marquee
duration: 20000,

//gap in pixels between the tickers
gap: 50,

//time in milliseconds before the marquee will start animating
delayBeforeStart: 2000,

//'left' or 'right'
direction: 'left',

//true or false - should the marquee be duplicated to show an effect of continues flow

duplicated: true
                                                                                                                         });
    });

                                                                                                         </script>
```

Comment: The first rule of using jquery plugins written by someone else, is to read the documentation :) http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin#pauseonhover

Comment: thank you so much. I didnt find the actual plugin, i googled jquery marquee and a JS fiddle came up. Thank you so much though! this is all new to me, so thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: No problem. For future reference, usually jQuery plugin developers will specify details about the plugin at the top of the js file in comments. //cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js